# How to define a crossword grid in XCode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, crossword

I want to implement a crossword puzzle as an iOS App. I’m happy with the Swift code to write the logic. But can’t work out how to setup the user interface to display a crossword grid with a mix of single-character input squares and blacked-out non-input squares.

My question: Does Interface Builder offer a View to draw a 15x15 matrix where each cell in the matrix can be configured by my Swift code? I have tried building a grid using 225 Text views with over 225 constraints to hold them all together but my mac has ground to a halt!

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and don’t create a complex view like this in Interface Builder. Also, what if you want to include a crossword puzzle, which is 16x15 instead?

Comment: If you do something like this in Interface Builder, all I'd do is set up a `UICollectionView`/`UICollectionViewController` and a custom cell or two. Other than that, this is definitely best done in code instead of IB

Comment: Thank you the4kman and Michael Hulet. I’m new to XCode (and stackoverflow) and will take your advice and learn how to do this in code.